# создание таблицы по: CREATE TABLE ##(тут имя переменной)

Tags: sql-server

Необходимо создать временную, глобальную таблицу с именем зависящей от переменной. Например:

```
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(max) = 'TempTableName'
CREATE TABLE ##@TableName([id] int)
```

Создаёт таблицу с именем `##@TableName`, а не с `##TempTableName`

Как правильно создать такую глобальную временную таблицу?

Comment: Попробуйте через хранимую процедуру `sp_executesql`, не знаю правда выполняет ли она DDL, но вдруг ...

Comment: @Mike, [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) выполняет любые запросы, на которые у пользователя хватает прав, в том числе и DDL. Советую оформить ваш комментарий как ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо воспользоватся хранимой процедурой [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188001(v=sql.120).aspx), которая может выполнять динамически собранный в виде строки запрос:

```
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(max) = 'TempTableName';
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(max) = 'create table ##' + @TableName +'([id] int)';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
```